# Ставить тире или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Этой мой вариант пунктуации:

«Движение – это жизнь». Если вы двигаетесь, значит живете, значит находитесь на пути к своей цели, словно спортсмен, который несет Олимпийский огонь!

Журналист предлагает ставить тире на месте "пропущенного" подлежащего:

«Движение – это жизнь». Если вы двигаетесь, значит - живете, значит - находитесь на пути к своей цели, словно спортсмен, который несет Олимпийский огонь!

Почему я не согласна с тире: По правилу тире вроде бы должно компенсировать пропущенный член предложения, но здесь имеет место (быть) или не быть правило интонационной постановки тире. В связи с этим, на мой взгляд, тире ставить не обязательно, при произношении паузы нет, связка "значит живете, значит находитесь на пути к своей цели" произносится без интонационных "остановок". Считаю тире в этом случае лишней пунктуационной нагрузкой на предложение.

При этом допускаю, что могу ошибаться, хотелось бы мнение эксперта.

Comment: >произносится без интонационных "остановок"

Пусть нет "остановки", но есть излом интонации. Без труда можно научиться проговаривать эту фразу на ровной интонации как мантру... и в скором времени погрузиться в прострацию без эксперта и медиума. Но у *письма* назначение иное, так ведь?

Answer (score 2):

Ольга, полностью с Вами согласна. «Движение – это жизнь».- тире между подлежащим и сказуемым в двусост. предл. Вполне приемлемо: "Если вы двигаетесь, значит живете, значит находитесь на пути к своей цели, словно спортсмен, который несет Олимпийский огонь!"(конструкция если...,значит = если...,то)

Возможна запятая после "значит": Если вы двигаетесь, значит,живете, значит, находитесь на пути к своей цели, словно спортсмен, который несет Олимпийский огонь!-значит - вводное.

Возможно и интонационное тире, так фраза более эмоциональна и  насыщенна: Если вы двигаетесь, значит - живете, значит - находитесь на пути к своей цели, словно спортсмен, который несет Олимпийский огонь!

Никакого именительного темы здесь нет.

Comment: Присоединяюсь. Хотя я тот еще корректор, но с логикой обоснования согласен полностью.

Answer (score 0):

При наличии слов-связок тире ставится всегда (это особого вида предложения с именительным темы, которые  рассмотрим ниже.Постановка тире между подлежащим и сказуемым соответствует паузе в устной речи в соответствии со следующей интонационной схемой: повышение тона –  увеличенная пауза – понижение тона.Принцип постановки тире - интонационно-грамматический.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

"По правилу тире вроде бы должно компенсировать пропущенный член предложения, но здесь имеет место (быть) или не быть правило интонационной постановки тире". Это верно для неполных предложений, но не относится к данной теме.По поводу интонации полностью согласна с Hermit: нельзя во всем полагаться на устную речь (у нее свои законы жизни), но надо обязательно ориентироваться на интонацию отдельного предложения - а здесь есть пауза.

МАТЕРИАЛ ДЛЯ ОЦЕНКИ ЭКСПЕРТАМИ (по поводу именительного темы).
В предложениях данного типа на первом месте стоит слово с предметным значением со статусом подлежащего, являющееся именительным темы. Затем после паузы следует местоимение ЭТО, замещающее указанное  слово и фактически играющее роль подлежащего, за которым следует сказуемое: Доверие – это ключ к сердцу.Приведённая трактовка предложений со словами-связками УДОБНА В ОСОБЫХ СЛУЧАЯХ, а именно:

А) при инверсии связки (связка расположена перед именительным темы):  Удивительный это народ – дети!

Б) при наличии связки в косвенном падеже (в роли дополнения, а не подлежащего): Признать свои ошибки – на это он не способен.

Фактически ВСЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ со словами-связками – это предложения с именительным темы, но  в них связка ЭТО стоит в И.п. и играет роль подлежащего.

Comment: Большое спасибо за содержательный ответ!

Comment: София, Вы не намудрили с именительным темы(представления)? Именительный  темы или представления - синтаксическая структура, стоящая перед предложением, тему которого она представляет, отделяется знаками препинания, соответствующими концу предложения, — точкой, воскл. знаком, вопрос. знаком, многоточием. Если после именительного темы стоит вопросительная часть конструкции, которая также представляет собой форму им. падежа, то ставится тире:  «Зеленая революция» — легенда или реальность? (возможна подстановка слова это)Его надо отличать от двусоставного предл.

Comment: Вот здесь об именительном темы: http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=63  Вашу ссылочку нельзя про "Фактически ВСЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ со словами-связками – это предложения с именительным темы, но в них связка ЭТО стоит в И.п. и играет роль подлежащего"? Откуда это смешение таких разных конструкций?

Comment: София, а действительно, чем Вы руководствуетесь, относя подобные предложения к именительному темы? "Именительный темы" - понятие скорее стилистическое, чем грамматическое. Поэтому возможны  некоторые колебания в подходах, но не до такой же степени?  
Я сейчас "не при делах", когда попадалось на глаза соображение, что И. темы можно трактовать шире, чем по учебнику, но Вы уж как-то очень радикально...

Comment: Эксперты не оценили (смайлик). К сожалению, я  давно работала над этой темой, под рукой ссылок нет. Точно помню (или почти точно), что от себя ничего не добавляла, по возможности попытаюсь найти источник (я уж точно не автор версии, мне она просто приглянулась). А кстати, что вас не устраивает по сути дела? У вас есть другие объяснения  структуры предложений со связкой ЭТО, в том числе для особых случаев?

Comment: >У вас есть другие объяснения структуры предложений со связкой ЭТО, в том числе для особых случаев?  
  
А какие такие "особые случаи"?  
  
ЗЫ не надо ссылок. Своими словами можете объяснить, зачем (или на каком основании) эти случаи относить к именительному темы? У Вас нет ничего - ну кроме декларации "фактически это именительный темы". Я такой фактичности здесь не вижу.

Comment: Особые случаи я назвала в ответе. Мне же интересно ваше мнение по поводу структуры подобных предложений и по поводу их происхождения. Можно считать, что мы называем предмет, а затем заменяем его указательным местоимением ЭТО, которое фактически является подлежащим в следующем после названия предложении? Вы считаете, что нет, а я не настаиваю. Это всего лишь версия, и в ответе об этом было сказано.
Для практической орфографии важно объяснить, почему перед связкой  всегда ставится тире, а для этого надо понять устройство предложения. Так почему оно (тире) всегда ставится? С вашей точки зрения.